# What are the benefits of hashing many times a password?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, hash

I've seen many examples where the password is hashed many times. For example, by default in Symfony, sha512 is applied 5000 times on the password.

I can understand something like 2-3 sha512 in a row to avoid retrieving the original password when the hash is known, but what is the need for applying it 5000 times? It increases a lot the collision risks, doesn't it?

What are the benefits?

Comment: IMHO security.stackexchange.com is a better place for this question, see e.g. http://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=multiple+hash or http://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=many+times

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming. This is better suited for either [security.se] (or even [crypto.se]).

Comment: @ArtjomB. This question is required on StackOverflow, because it's a very common mistake to hash several times. This question has nothing to do with cryptography, but is the most common software design. One doesn't have to be a cryptographer to write servers.

Answer (score -1):

That's a stupid insecure way of making a bruteforce attack infeasible by slowing it down 5000 times. The author of whatever you're reading really has to know about `bcrypt` or `scrypt`. Tell him.

Comment: The question is *"I can understand something like 2-3 sha512 [...], but what is the need for applying it 5000 times?"* It doesn't look like you answered the question. Hashing 5000 times certainly has some value if compared to 2 or 3 times. Also, bcrypt and scrypt essentially make the same thing, only with a salt and more iterations (cost) and a slightly more elaborate way of applying the iterations.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Hashing 5000 times results in a much smaller set of values, the fixed points of hash function, and thus breaks security. Bcrypt's "slightly more elaborate way of applying the iterations" is what makes it cryptographically secure.

Comment: Ok, so that's closer to an actual answer to this question. Still not there. That's why [security.se] is much better suited, because this question would have been either closed as duplicate or properly answered within minutes.